# Automatic Website user password generation

Tags: users, user-registration

I have created a ticketing system on my website, so users can log in and request a call out.

However wordpress is currently set so that any new users need an administrator to log in and generate them a password, and then email it out.

Is there any way to set up a system where a user has their password automatically generated and sent to them? ideally I am trying to cut out having to log in for every new user.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can create password for your user using [`wp_generate_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) and send them using [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/).

Comment: @MayeenulIslam yes, but IMHO, sending a password via e-mail, is not a good idea.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz yap, always. I's just solving their problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now realised there was a difference to registering on the site and through wordpress. When registering for the site a user can set up their own password, but through wordpress it asks you to check your email for a password that never arrives.

Long story short, problem solved. Thanks to everyone for their input!

Answer (score 1):

In *Settings -> General -> Membership* check the box *Anyone can register*.

This setting allows new user to register and receive an e-mail with a link to reset his password. This method does not involve the administrator and it is secure, because no passwords are being send via e-mail.

Comment: this is already ticked, yet when i created a test account i didn't get a link to create the new password/ reset the password

Comment: If you register as a new user, using *Register* link of login form, two e-mails will be send, one for the administrator ( ignore it ), and one for the new user. In the new user's e-mail, there are two links, The first one points to reset password form. For testing purpose, use your second e-mail address, so you can get the new user's e-mail message.